# Circuit for charging 3.7 volt battery using a motor rotated mechanically

Tags: battery-charging, dc-motor

I took a 5 volt DC motor, and tried to rotate it at its maximum speed by hand. During its rotation I measured the voltage at the motors i/p wires. It comes out to be 4.5 volts. Now I want to use this DC 4.5 V to charge a mobile phone 3.7 volts battery. Can someone give me pointers for designing such a charger with circuit dig ?

**Note:**
In actual case I will have a mechanism that will keep rotating the motors wings continuously at its maximum speed. It will not be hand rotated as I am doing it for the testing purpose.

Comment: Such questions that simply require a Google search are closed.

Comment: What would you do to protect the electronics from turning the motor in the wrong direction? What mechanism turns the motor?

Answer (score 1):

You need a diode or a diode bridge, and then a charger IC. You should better use brushless motor of higher voltage and diode bridge. Or actually there are special generators of this kind available, for example bicycle usb charger.

Comment: Can you tell me the purpose of diode/diode bridge ? Also please suggest me some charger ICs which I should use.